# How can I match an exact string with variable text before and behind the string in PHP?

Tags: regex, preg-match

I' use a small validation script that tells me when a given url is blocked by robots.txt.

For example there is a given url like http://www.example.com/dir/test.html

My current script tells me if the url is blocked, when there is a line in robots.txt like:

```
Disallow: /test1.html
```

But it also says that the url is blocked when there are lines like:

```
Disallow: /tes
```

Thats wrong.

I googled something like "regex exact string" and found lots of solutions for the problem above.

But this leads to another problem. When I check exact string in an url http://www.example.com/dir/test1/page.html and in robots.txt is a line like

```
Disallow: /test1/page.html
```

My script doesn't get it because it looks for

```
Disallow: /dir/test1/page.html
```

And says: That the target page.html is not blocked - but it is!

How can I match an exact string with variable text before and behind the string?

Here is the short-version of the script:

```
/* example for $rules */
$rules = array("/tes", "/test", "/test1", "/test/page.html", "/test1/page.html", "/dir/test1/page.html")

/*example for $parsed['path']:*/
"dir/test.html"
"dir/test1/page.html"
"test1/page.html"

foreach ($rules as $rule) {
  // check if page is disallowed to us
  if (preg_match("/^$rule/", $parsed['path']))
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT:**
This is the whole function:

```
function robots_allowed($url, $useragent = false) {
// parse url to retrieve host and path
$parsed = parse_url($url);

$agents = array(preg_quote('*'));
if ($useragent)
  $agents[] = preg_quote($useragent);
$agents = implode('|', $agents);

// location of robots.txt file
$robotstxt = !empty($parsed['host']) ? @file($parsed['scheme'] . "://" . $parsed['host'] . "/robots.txt") : "";

// if there isn't a robots, then we're allowed in
if (empty($robotstxt))
  return true;

$rules = array();
$ruleApplies = false;
foreach ($robotstxt as $line) {
  // skip blank lines
  if (!$line = trim($line))
    continue;

  // following rules only apply if User-agent matches $useragent or '*'
  if (preg_match('/^\s*User-agent: (.*)/i', $line, $match)) {
    $ruleApplies = preg_match("/($agents)/i", $match[1]);
  }
  if ($ruleApplies && preg_match('/^\s*Disallow:(.*)/i', $line, $regs)) {
    // an empty rule implies full access - no further tests required
    if (!$regs[1])
      return true;
    // add rules that apply to array for testing
    $rules[] = preg_quote(trim($regs[1]), '/');
  }
}

foreach ($rules as $rule) {
  // check if page is disallowed to us
  if (preg_match("/^$rule/", $parsed['path']))
    return false;
}

// page is not disallowed
return true;
```

}

The URL comes from user input.

Comment: Your script shouldn't tell you the given URL http://www.example.com/dir/test.html is blocked by `Disallow: /test1.html` either. Because it is `test.html` and not `test1.html`.

Comment: Yes, but it also tells me `/test2/test1.html` is blocked when I ask for `test`.

Comment: Your regex probably should be `"/$rule$/"`

Comment: What exactly is variable and what exactly isn't ?

Comment: Thank you.I tested it but this allows the line: `Disallow: /test` when I check an url like `http://localhost/test/test1.html`

Comment: @sln the variable `$rule` is an array element type of string. `$parsed['path']` is type of string an the path behind the host. It's the part of and url after http://example.com

Comment: Do your _rules_ need to be matched at the end of the line ?

Comment: Here this is everything. Add anchors where needed. `/(?:\/?dir\/)?\/?tes(?:(?:t(?:1)?)?(?:\.html|(?:\/page\.html)?))/` https://regex101.com/r/VxL30W/1

Answer (score 0):

Try *everything* at once, avoid the array.

```
/(?:\/?dir\/)?\/?tes(?:(?:t(?:1)?)?(?:\.html|(?:\/page\.html)?))/
```

https://regex101.com/r/VxL30W/1

```
 (?: /?dir / )?

 /?tes 
 (?:
      (?:
           t 
           (?: 1 )?
      )?
      (?:
           \.html
        |  
           (?: /page \. html )?

      )
 )
```

Comment: Thanks, but this works with '/dir/test1/page.html' only. The URL changes. The URL comes from user Input. The robots.txt is variable too.

Comment: @user_name - `works with '/dir/test1/page.html' only` And what doesn't it work with again ?

Comment: Your regex example only works with this specific example  '/dir/test1/page.html'. It won't work with '/foobar/helloworld' and '/foo' as search pattern. The URL comes from user input.

Comment: What exactly is variable and what exactly isn't ? If you have a known text from user input, all you have to do is construct your own regex from it. `'.*?' . $input . '.*?'`

Comment: What about this one?: (?:\/test). This matches /test but not /tes or /test2 or am I wrong with that? https://regex101.com/r/DFVR5T/1

Comment: @user_name - You start out with unknown user input, say `/test`. What can you hardcode to get matches ? Well, nothing. Hardcode means making rules ahead of time, that work on the variable input. You can create a regex from the input, but only with the rules set ahead of time. For example you could make everything past the first 2 letters optional. `(?:/te(?:s(?:t)?)?`

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's not about `/test` or `/test/`. The input follows some rules given for disabled lines in a robots.txt. `test` was just an example.
As you can see, the $rule in `preg_match("/(?:" . $rule . "$|" . $rule . ")/", $parsed['path']` is not hardcoded ;-) Its for filtering strings in an URL with or without trailing `/` as shown in the examples.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to match `/test` or `/test/hello` or `/test/` but not to match `/testosterone` or `/hellotest`:

`(?:\/test$|\/test\/)`

With PHP-Variables:

`if (preg_match("/(?:" . $rule . "$|" . $rule . "\/)/", $parsed['path']))`

Based on the funktion above.

https://regex101.com/r/DFVR5T/3

Can I use `(?:\/` ...`)` or is that wrong?